# Add-AzureADUser Powershell

Tags: azure-powershell

Having issues trying to get my loop grab each member's ObjectID then adding those members into an AD group using the Add-AzureADGroupMember cmdlet. Any help would be great. Thank you

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module AzureAD

#2Checks for users with admin roles

$RolesCollection = @()
$Roles = Get-MsolRole
ForEach ($Role In $Roles){
  $Members = Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $Role.ObjectId
  ForEach ($Member In $Members) {
    $data = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      RoleName = $Role.Name
      MemberName = $Member.DisplayName
      MemberObjectID = $Member.ObjectId
    }
    $RolesCollection += $data
  }
#Adds users with admin roles into PIM group via member object ID
  forEach ($objectID in $RolesCollection){
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 'removed ObjectID for security concerns' -RefObjectId $($Member.ObjectId)
}
}
```

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my code below:

```
$RolesCollection = @()
$Roles = Get-MsolRole
ForEach ($Role In $Roles){
  $Members = Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $Role.ObjectId
  ForEach ($Member In $Members) {
    $data = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      RoleName = $Role.Name
      MemberName = $Member.DisplayName
      MemberObjectID = $Member.ObjectId
    }
    $RolesCollection += $data
  }
#Adds users with admin roles into PIM group via member object ID
      forEach ($user in $RolesCollection){

 

      #check if the user exists in the AAD Group, if not, add into it.
      $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 'removed ObjectID for security concerns' | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectId
        If ($members -contains $user) {
            continue
         } Else {
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 'removed ObjectID for security concerns' -RefObjectId $($user.MemberObjectID)
         }

      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm still getting the same error code as before.

Comment: dd-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more added object references already exist for the following modified 
properties: 'members'.